# How do I compute the probability that there is at least one ball of each of the colors red, blue or black?

Tags: probability

I have the following:

> In a box there are three balls of each color red, blue, violet and black. Pick $4$ of them. What is the probability that there is at least one of each of the colors blue, red, black?

I somehow struggle a bit with all the possibilities. So my idea was to define $\Omega=\{f:\{1,2,3\}\rightarrow \{r,r,r,b,b,b,v,v,v,bl,bl,bl\}, f\text{ is injective}\}$, then $|\Omega|=12\cdot11\cdot 10\cdot 9$.

Now I wanted to define $\Lambda\subset \Omega$ containing $(a,b,c,d)$ such that they contain at least one red, one blue and one black ball. But somehow I don’t see how to compute all the possibilities to commute the possibilities with Laplace.

Comment: "There are three balls of color red, blue, violett and black. Pick 4 of them" makes no sense. I presume you mean that there are three balls of *each* of these colours?

Comment: Ah yes I mean three of each of these colors, so in total 12

Comment: I‘ve edited it now, hope you can help me now

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are $$\binom{12}{4}$$ ways to select four of the twelve balls.

For the favorable cases, there are two possibilities:

1. One ball of each color is selected.
2. All four balls are red, blue, or black.

*One ball of each color is selected*: For each of the four colors, there are three ways to choose a ball of that color, giving $$\binom{3}{1}\binom{3}{1}\binom{3}{1}\binom{3}{1}$$ possible outcomes for this case.

*All four balls are red, blue, or black*:  For this to occur, two balls drawn from one of these three colors and one ball each is drawn from the other two of these colors.  There are three ways to select the color from which two balls are drawn, $\binom{3}{2}$ ways to select two of the three balls of that color, and three ways to choose a ball from each of the two colors from which one ball each is drawn.  Hence, there are $$\binom{3}{1}\binom{3}{2}\binom{3}{1}\binom{3}{1}$$ such cases.

Since these two cases are mutually exclusive and exhaustive, the number of favorable cases is
$$\binom{3}{1}\binom{3}{1}\binom{3}{1}\binom{3}{1} + \binom{3}{1}\binom{3}{2}\binom{3}{1}\binom{3}{1}$$

Hence, the probability that there is at least one ball of each of the colors red, blue, and black is
$$\frac{\dbinom{3}{1}\dbinom{3}{1}\dbinom{3}{1}\dbinom{3}{1} + \dbinom{3}{1}\dbinom{3}{2}\dbinom{3}{1}\dbinom{3}{1}}{\dbinom{12}{4}}$$

Answer (score 1):

There are $3^3=27$ ways to pick one ball of each desired colour, and then $3$ ways to pick a ball of the remaining colour and $6$ ways to pick another ball of one of the three colours. Picking another ball of the remaining colour yields $27\cdot3=81$ possibilities. Picking another ball of one of the three colours yields $27\cdot6=162$ possibilities, but each of them is counted twice (depending on the order of the balls with the same colour), so that makes another $81$ distinct possibilities, for a total of $81+81=162$. Overall, there are $\binom{12}4=495$ ways to pick $4$ out of $12$ balls, so the desired probability is $\frac{162}{495}=\frac{18}{55}$.

Answer (score 1):

The first three figures denote mandatory colors in favorable patterns.

There are $3$ possible permutations of the mandatory colors in pattern $\;\;2-1-1-0\;\;$ and one in $\;\;1-1-1-1$

Thus, using the hypergeometric formula,

$Pr = \dfrac{3\cdot\binom32\binom31\binom31\binom30 + \binom31\binom31\binom31\binom31}{\binom{12}4} $

Answer (score 1):

There are $\binom{12}{4}$ ways to select $4$ balls, all of which we assume are equally likely.

Let's say a selection of $4$ balls has "Property $i$" if there are no balls of color $i$, for $i \in \{red,blue,black\}$.  We want the probability that the selection has none of the properties.  By inclusion/exclusion, the probability is
$$1 - \frac{\binom{3}{1} \binom{9}{4}}{\binom{12}{4}} + \frac{\binom{3}{2} \binom{6}{4}}{\binom{12}{4}} = \frac{162}{495}$$